# Drupal cache not working (tables empty)

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, centos

I am having a problem with several Drupal 7 distributions running on CentOS 5, Apache 2, PHP 5, MySQL 5. Several of the `cache_*` tables are empty and are not being filled up, no matter what I do, and that is the reason why my AJAX login form isn't working (I've debugged the core and traced it down to the `form_get_cache` function returning empty).

I have the **exact** same code and DB running on a Windows 7 machine, and the cache tables are being populated with no problem.

Did anyone stumble upon something like this and can point me in a direction? I've really tried everything and nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugged a little more into the core and found out what the problem was: Memcache.

I was using memcache with Drupal on the CentOS servers, but not on the Windows one. Seems like Drupal doesn't work 100% correct with Memcache yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is related: [Drupal cache not working - tables remain empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993322/drupal-cache-not-working-tables-remain-empty/)

It's necessary to remove/uncomment the following line from settings.php after disabling the memcache module:

```
$conf['cache_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
```